# JavaFX TextFlow - empty Text Node not displaying empty (stealing character from adjacent Text)

Tags: java, javafx, textflow

[This is how the window looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTDhO.png)

The issue here is that the center `Text` (blue) should be empty, but for some reason is not. 
The window is just a very simple JavaFX `Application`. The start method looks like this:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Pane main = new Pane();
    TextProgress copy = new TextProgress();
    main.getChildren().add(copy);

    Scene scene = new Scene(main, 300, 200);
    stage.setTitle("Test");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

`TextProgress` is a custom class that is basically a `TextFlow` with three `Text` Nodes in it. The contents of the three `Texts` is: "Hello ", "" (empty), "World". The problem is, as you can see in the image, that the `Text` in the middle 'stole' a character from the one on the right.

Before showing the code of `TextProgress`, let me list a few things that I've found while playing around with this, as to make the code understandable.

- This entire code is just to show the problem, the original application was basically something to display the progress of copying a text by hand. The left `Text` would contain all the words that were already typed, the center `Text` the current word to type, and the right `Text` the text yet to type.
- Furthermore, the center `Text` was split once more into a `Text` for the typed and untyped characters for the current word. In this example the "Hello" would be an already typed word, the empty `Text` would be the typed characters of the current word, and "World" would be the untyped characters of the current word. (Since we are not typing anything in this example, the other `Text` was left out.)
- The reason I did not leave out the "Hello" is that the issue only occurs when there is a `Text` in front of the center `Text` (doesn't matter if empty or not).
- Another way to prevent the issue is wrapping the two `Texts` for the current word in another `TextFlow`. `(Text, TextFlow[Text,Text], Text)`. While this seems to solve the issue, it causes a different one. While typing text, and thus changing the contents of the `Texts`, the word wrap of the line currently being typed changes from time to time, e.g. a long word gets pushed down into the next line while being typed, then goes back up on the next word again. Note that this happens even though the combined length of all `Texts` always stays the same. This might be related to the issue of this question?
- The only difference between the different `Texts` is the color. Regarding the other issue mentioned above, does this explain the changing word wrap?
- The issue only ever occurred on the first character of the current word. Once the center `Text` (blue) is not empty anymore, everything is as expected.
- I made sure the empty `Text` is actually empty
- I added some prints for the `BoundingBox` of the center `Text` before and after displaying the window, the width attribute here is 0 before, ~28 afterwards.
- If the two `Texts` for the current word are wrapped in another `TextFlow`, the width attribute here changes from 0 to -1. Is there a way to set the width of the empty `Text` to -1 without the additional `TextFlow`?

(Not sure whether to include just the `TextProgress` class here, or the entire `Application`, since the entire class is small.)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Window extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Pane main = new Pane();
    TextProgress copy = new TextProgress();
    main.getChildren().add(copy);

    Scene scene = new Scene(main, 300, 200);
    stage.setTitle("Test");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private static class TextProgress extends TextFlow {

    private Text typed;
    private TextFlow current;
    private Text currentTyped;
    private Text currentUntyped;

    public TextProgress() 
    {
        double size = 30;
        boolean wrap = false;

        typed = new Text();
        typed.setFont(Font.font(size));
        typed.setFill(Color.ORANGERED);
        typed.setText("Hello ");

        currentTyped = new Text();
        currentTyped.setFont(Font.font(size));
        currentTyped.setFill(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE);
        currentTyped.setText("");
        printDelayed(1000);

        currentUntyped = new Text();
        currentUntyped.setFont(Font.font(size));
        currentUntyped.setFill(Color.MEDIUMAQUAMARINE);
        currentUntyped.setText("World");

        if (wrap) {
            current = new TextFlow();
            current.getChildren().addAll(currentTyped, currentUntyped);
            this.getChildren().addAll(typed, current);
        } else {                
            this.getChildren().addAll(typed, currentTyped, currentUntyped);
        }
    }

    private void printDelayed(long delay) {
        System.out.println(currentTyped.getLayoutBounds());
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(currentTyped.getLayoutBounds());
        }).start();
    }
}
}
```

I appreciate any clues as to what is going on here. Again, the main question here is how to stop the center `Text` from displaying some character from the adjacent `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i am guessing you are doing, which should work from the way my head is vibrating now :)

You have a `TextFlow` which has 3 `Text` (or `Label`) `Node`s, respectively typed, untyped,currenttyped, all with the initial text `" "`.

Now when you type the key strokes are updated in the typed and currenttyped, and you conjure the next set of words and update it to untyped.

so it should work, because `Textflow` is just a horizontal,wrappable node of nodes, so if you have `Label`s or `Text` with different Paints all you have to do is update those respective nodes `textProperty()`, and i guess they will wrap on their own.

Hope it helped you Sir.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're answering here, which might be my fault for not having a more clear question. In what environment is the TextFlow you're mentioning? The typing application requires at least 4 Text nodes and it doesn't matter how I update the contents. The character stealing issue occurs not only initially, but on every single word from the full text (while progressing). This simple application obviously doesn't have any typing progression included (since it isn't relevant to the issue).